How to deal with wasb error in mounting azure databricks with containers?
Error in Azure Databricks
Expecting successful output after mounting the container to databricks. I have used wasb for mounting purpose.
Error states: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container tokyo-olympic-data in account tokyoolympicdatasg.blob.core.windows.net using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them  in the configuration.
Couldn't figure out the error as my authentication is absolute.

Please do not share confidential information (passwords and secrets)

In your config you declare the provider - "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider".
So you need to start your source with "abfss://" and not "wasbs://"
abfss - is for Azure data lake storage
wasbs - is for accessing blob storage

Whenever you need to read from or store files in Blob Storage or ADLS Gen2, it is mandatory to mount it using either a SAS token or an Account Access Key.
Below is the syntax/code for Blob Storage.
Step 1: Blob Storage account Access Key or SAS Token.

I have tried the following approach:
storageAcc = "dileepstgacc"
storageAccessKey = "D1BD/sSgllh2rdLxN5RKQQ873GMh64ecD4MNTyAty61/3X3QR7XgcriXfdNCycggCbt/4BmUMXni+ASto8s28A=="
#sasToken = <sas-token>
Container = "folder02"
mountPoint = "/mnt/new"
if any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  print("mountPoint--> ",mountPoint)
  dbutils.fs.unmount(mountPoint)
  print("End of Unmount")
try:
  dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://{}@{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(Container, storageAcc),
    mount_point = mountPoint,
    #extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.' + storageAcc + '.blob.core.windows.net': storageAccessKey}
    extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.{0}.blob.core.windows.net'.format(storageAcc): storageAccessKey}
    #extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.{0}.blob.core.windows.net".format(Container):sasToken}
    #extra_configs = {'fs.azure.sas.' + Container + '.' + storageAcc + '.blob.core.windows.net': sasToken}
  )
  print("mount succeeded!")
except Exception as e:
  print("mount exception", e)

Results:

If you want to mount ADLS Gen2 instead of Blob Storage, you only need to make a very minor change in the same code, which is highlighted below in bold.
For Blob Storage: wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net/
For ADLS Gen2: abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/
The full form of wasbs is Windows Azure Storage Blob.
The full form of abfs is Azure Blob File System.
To check all mounted paths, use the command below:
dbutils.fs.mounts()

To unmount:
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/new")

Reference:
Mount Blob Storage and ADLS Gen2 in Azure Databricks
